# Problem with bash readarray -t array assignment when jq outputs an empty string

Tags: arrays, bash, indexing, jq, content-length

First - a very simple code:

```
#!/bin/bash

a_string="string"
readarray -t a <<<"$a_string"
echo "${a[@]}"
echo "${#a[@]}"

# read empty string into array
emptystring=""
readarray -t b <<<"$emptystring"
echo "${b[@]}"
echo "${#b[@]}"

# and now - empty array
c=()
echo "${c[@]}"
echo "${#c[@]}"
```

And the output

```
string
1

1

0
```

So reading an empty string into bash array with `readarray -t` shows array length as 1. And only truly empty array's length is 0.

My question - why it is happening?

As my case - here is a fragment from my script - execute an API call, get JSON, and apply jq filter:

```
URL_list_json=$(curl -s --request GET "$curl_request" --header "Authorization: Bearer ${token}")
readarray -t URL_names <<<"$(echo "$URL_list_json" | jq -r '.[].Body.monitors[].name')"
```

Here is an example of JSON which results an empty array from the jq call:

```
[
    {
        "Header": {
            "Region": "dc1",
            "Tenant": "tenant1",
            "Stage": "test"
        },
        "Body": {
            "monitors": []
        }
    }
]
```

and here is JSON with populated content returning a non-empty array from jq call:

```
[
    {
        "Header": {
            "Region": "dc2",
            "Tenant": "tenant2",
            "Stage": "qa"
        },
        "Body": {
            "monitors": [
                {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "entityId": "TEST-674BA97E74FC74AA",
                    "name": "production.example.com"
                },
                {
                    "enabled": false,
                    "entityId": "TEST-3E2D23438A973D1E",
                    "name": "test.example.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I need to check if `URL_names` array is empty or not. If not empty, then iterate over contents. If empty - means that jq did not return any results - white to log and move on.

If I use `if ((${#URL_names[@]}))` as a means to check if the array is empty or not, it will return 1 even if the array has just an empty string from the jq call, so this logic fails.

What are alternative approaches to deal with the case like above?

I can assign the output of the jq filter to a string and then use **if** statement to check if the string is empty and if non-empty then assign the string to an array, but this introduces additional elements. With this approach, I can skip using arrays entirely - I was hoping to use only arrays for this task.

Thanks

Comment: `an empty string` that's not an empty string, it has one newline.

Comment: Did you try it with `read -a` instead of `mapfile`/`readarray`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> why it is happening?

Because it reads one line. From [bash manual here document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html):

> [n]<<< word

> [...] The result is supplied as a single string, **with a newline appended**, to the command on its standard input (or file descriptor n if n is specified).

Because there is a newline, `readarray` reads one empty line. You may do:

```
readarray -t b < <(printf "%s" "$emptystring")
```

Notes:

- `echo "$var"` is not preferred. Do `printf "%s" "$var"` when in posix shell, do `<<<"$var"` when in bash (and you do not care about the extra newline).
- `<<<"$(...)"` always looks strange - the `<<<` has to allocate a subshell anyway. Do `< <(...)`.
- You want to do: `readarray -t URL_names < <(<<<"$URL_list_json" jq -r '.[].Body.monitors[].name')`
- If you want to check if the array is empty, check that in `jq`. [I see ex.](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1272) `jq --exit-status '.[].Body.monitors[].name'` and just check the exit status.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't think that jq's exit status will work in my case because all I want to see is what is the result of jq's call and based on that result make decisions. If I need to check exit status first and then based on the exit status to do another jq call - that's a duplication of efforts.

Comment: Seems this construct
``readarray -t URL_names < <( jq -r '. [].Body.monitors[].name' <<<"$URL_list_json" | sort)`` should do the job.

Comment: `If I need to check exit status first and then based on the exit status to do another jq call - that's a duplication of efforts` ? just `if ! output=$(jq something); then echo no data; fi`

Comment: Another alternative uses the `-n` option of `echo` to refrain from printing a trailing new line: `readarray -t b < <(echo -n $emptystring)`